# H2 ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT only if table exists

Tags: h2

I need to drop a constraint (say, foreign key). But *the table*, the constraint on it, or both, may not exist.

I tried:

- `ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS Table1` - invalid syntax
- `ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS Constraint` - fails if Table1 is missing
- funky CASE WHEN stuff like

  `select CASE (select count(*)
               from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINTS
               where CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'DBO'
                 and CONSTRAINT_NAME = upper('FK_Table1_Col1_Table2_Col2'))
           WHEN 1 THEN 'select 5'
           end`

In MS SQL for example you have all the IF EXISTS clauses allowing you to branch script easily. Not so with H2, it would seem. There should be some way to make it work similar to my attempt with CASE WHEN, no ?

If possible, I want to avoid writing Java code in the sql file.